# Intercept and edit a request body/payload using an userscript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Couldn't find the answer for this while using an userscript.
Is it possible to modify a request body inside an userscript in tampermonkey for example?
I could patch the open function to modify type and url, but I couldn't access the request body